# Get sessions percentage from Google Analytics(GAPI)

Tags: google-analytics, metrics, dimensions, google-api-js-client

I need to get sessions percentage from Google Analytics. However, i can able to get percentage of new sessions from following documentation.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_percentnewsessions

[This outcome is needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f19Gc.jpg)

is there any metric or any other way to retrieve this.

here is my code in which i can easily get sessions and percent of new sessions value but cant able to get sessions percentage only.

```
  var mainChart5 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
query: {
  'ids': "ga:"+data[0]['viewId'],
  'dimensions': 'ga:operatingSystem',
  'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:percentNewSessions',
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'today',
},
chart: {
  type: 'TABLE',
  container: 'main-chart-5-container',
  options: {
    // width: '100%'
  }
}
```

});

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I managed to do this by custom calculation.